# Terminate and restart Google DataLab instance?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-datalab, pandas-profiling

I am finding when working with larger datasets that the kernel may die, something I also experiance on my local machine. Sometimes it comes back and sometimes not. So even the Tree panel won't react to terminate a errant Kernel. EG "restart" does not work and the server itself seems to die. So the tree view won't respond or refresh. On my local machine I just kill the terminal instance and start over.

What is the "proper" way to restart everything?

FWIW the instance seems pegged at 150% cpu utilization atm

Related: is there any way to allow long running stuff to work?
I am trying to use a report generator (pandas-profiling) on a 2mm record dataset.. Works on my local..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it here: https://cloud.google.com/datalab/getting-started

FWIW These commands can be used in the new command line shell on the Cloud console page.see https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/ .. Without the sdk on your machine.. You need to modify the commands slightly since you will be logged into your project already,

Stopping/starting VM instances

You may want to stop a Cloud Datalab managed VM instance to avoid incurring ongoing charges. To stop a Cloud Datalab managed machine instance, go to a command prompt, and run:

```
$ gcloud auth login
$ gcloud config set project <YOUR PROJECT ID>
$ gcloud preview app versions stop main
```

After confirming that you want to continue, wait for the command to complete, and make sure that the output indicates that the version has stopped. If you used a non-default instance name when deploying, please use that name instead of "main" in the stop command, above (and in the start command, below).
For restarting a stopped instance, run:

```
$ gcloud auth login
$ gcloud config set project <YOUR PROJECT ID>
$ gcloud preview app versions start main
```